# "foreach" causes my function to misbehave

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to make the following work:

```
<?php

$item1 = A;
$item2 = B;
$item3 = C;

$array = array($item1, $item2, $item3);

function myFunction () {
    if ($item = "A") {
        echo "Alpha ";
        } 
    elseif ($item = "B") {
        echo "Bravo ";
        }
    elseif ($item = "C") {
        echo "Charlie ";
        }
    else {
        echo "Error";
        }
    }

foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction ();
    }

?>
```

The intended effect is that for each item, if the value is `A`, `echo "Alpha"`, `B` `echo "Bravo"` and `C` `echo "Charlie"`.

However, the output is as follows:

```
Alpha Alpha Alpha
```

There were no errors in the error log, so I'm guessing I must have made some kind of mistake not pertaining to syntax. I added an `echo $item;` before `myFunction`, and the output is as follows:

```
AAlpha BAlpha CAlpha
```

Which means that the $item has been correctly assigned A, B and C. Why doesn't myFunction work like intended?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The `=` is the assignment operator and may not be used for comparisons. Try `==` or `===` instead.

2) You assigned `$item1 = A` but compared `$item = "A"`. However `A` and `"A"` are usually different.

3) You didn't pass `$item` to the function.

In the first `if` statement you assign `"A"` to `$item` and then print out `"Alpha"` “if `"A"`”.

Your code should probably look something like this:

```
<?php

$item1 = "A";
$item2 = "B";
$item3 = "C";

$array = array($item1, $item2, $item3);

function myFunction ($item) {
    if ($item == "A") {
        echo "Alpha ";
        } 
    elseif ($item == "B") {
        echo "Bravo ";
        }
    elseif ($item == "C") {
        echo "Charlie ";
        }
    else {
        echo "Error";
        }
    }

foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction ($item);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using == instead, but this time I got no output.

Comment: Well, you assigned `$item1 = A` not `$item1 = "A"`. There's a difference.

Comment: I've added double quotes to each assignment, but I'm still getting no output though.

Comment: I copied the one you pasted, but now it says "ErrorErrorError".

Comment: Try working in the changes by hand. Also mind the third point, which I noticed rather late.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101019/discussion-between-hermann-doppes-and-daryl).

Comment: Thank you so much Hermann, for helping and for the patience! It's working now. I don't know how I missed that, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Set $item parametar on your function.

```
$item1 = "A";
$item2 = "B";
$item3 = "C";

$array = array($item1, $item2, $item3);


function myFunction($item){
    if($item == "A"){
        echo 'Alpha'.'<br/>';
    }

    elseif ($item == "B") {
        echo 'Bravo'.'<br/>';
    }

    elseif ($item == "C") {
        echo 'Charlie'.'<br/>';
    }

}


foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction($item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was one of the problems!

Answer (score 1):

Also, are you going to pass the variable to your function or what? Otherwise, as it is right now, it should only output "error."

Your function does not have an argument.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
myFunction ();
}
```

How about passing the $item so that your function can actually work:

```
function myFunction($item) {
```

and therefore:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
myFunction($item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've gotten an answer to the question. I should be using == instead of = for comparisons, and I didn't pass the $item to the function.

Comment: Why so rude? Also, there were already two other answers pointing this out.

Comment: I wasn't being rude, Hermann. You, however are being rude towards me when I'm simply trying to assist somebody. If you feel I was being rude it's  because you're choosing to read it that way. If my intention was to be rude, I wouldn't have responded in the first place. If I posted something that was already posted it's because they were posted as I was in the process of posting mine. Lastly, If you could discontinue attacking me and criticizing everything I post, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$item1 = "A";
$item2 = "B";
$item3 = "C";

$array = array($item1, $item2, $item3);

function myFunction ($item) {
    if ($item == "A") {
        echo "Alpha ";
        } 
    elseif ($item == "B") {
        echo "Bravo ";
        }
    elseif ($item == "C") {
        echo "Charlie ";
        }
    else {
        echo "Error";
        }
    }

foreach ($array as $item) {
    myFunction ($item);
    }

?>
```